# Postmaster parcels not sending

Tags: postmaster

In Postmaster I have setup a parcel to send once an entry in the store orders channel (id="13") has been entered as a status of closed to replicate and abandoned cart notification. For some reason I don't get the notification. In the control panel log I can see: "parcel does not have a valid channel_id, which is '1'."

Also have another parcel to a post date and can see the email is scheduled to send "The email  been added to the queue and is set to be sent at 2015-11-25 12:08." but never receive the mail. A cron job has been setup to ping the URL. Testing the URL I get "Mandrill Service - Error: The requested URL returned error: 500"

Any suggestions on how to fix these errors?